# I am getting "docker: invalid reference format." in my local machine

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to run postgresql container in my local (Windows 10 machine). i am using this command :

```
docker run -d --name pg-docker --restart=always --publish 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -v C:\Program Files\Docker\Volumes\pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:alpine
```

but its returning "docker: invalid reference format." error.

(P.S. I have my postgresql image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-v C:\Program Files\Docker\Volumes\pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data` is read as two separate arguments due to the space in "Program Files". So "Files\Docker\Volumes\pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data" is interpreted as the docker image name.

Escape the space with a `\` or wrap the path in quotes.